# Codeigniter JOIN multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm having a little trouble in retrieving data in multiple tables using codeigniter.

This is the code i'm using to retrieve data in my model which is working well.

```
function retrieve_experience($alumni_id)
{
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('experience');
$this->db->where('alumni_id',$alumni_id);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query;  
}

function retrieve_education($alumni_id)
{
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('education');
$this->db->where('alumni_id',$alumni_id);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query;
}
```

Now i tried using a simplified code but fails to display the data. here is the code in my model

```
function retrieve_all_data($alumni_id)
{
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('experience');
$this->db->join('education','education.alumni_id=experience.alumni_id');
$this->db->where('experience.alumni_id',$alumni_id);
$query=$this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
}
```

In my controller, i used this code to retrieving data in my model

```
function display()
{
$alumni_id = $this->session->userdata('alumni_id');
$data['all_data'] = $this->Alumni_model->retrieve_all_data($alumni_id);
$data['main_content'] = 'alumni_home';
$this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
}
```

and for the display i used this code

```
foreach($all_data as $results)
{
/** data from experience table **/
$results['company_name']; 
$results['company_address'];
/** data from education table **/
$results['school_name'];
$results['field_of_study'];
}
```

I cant display anything at all. Please help

Comment: You have any SQL error? Try enable codeigniter profiler to see what query you actual running.

Comment: On view `echo $results['company_name']; ` or `<?php echo $results['company_name'];?>`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 yes i used echo, still no output.. forgot to put echo on my question. my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code,

I believe you'll want something like this:

```
function retrieve_all_data($alumni_id)
{
  $this->db->select("e.*,edu.*");
  $this->db->from("experience e");
  $this->db->join("education edu", "edu.alumni_id = e.alumni_id",'left');
  $this->db->where('e.alumni_id',$alumni_id);
  $this->db->group_by('e.exp_id');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: it only displayed 1 result instead of 3 when i added 
    $this->db->group_by('e.alumni_id');

Comment: @Chris how do you actually want it??

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/8aDta

i want to display all the data in EXPERIENCE table WHERE alumni_id  = $alumni_id.

in my experience table, there are 3 entries in alumni_id=14

in the 1st image, it displayed 3 data, (using my old function
    function retrieve_experience($alumni_id)
 {
 $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('experience');
        $this->db->where('alumni_id',$alumni_id);
 $query = $this->db->get();
 return $query; 
 }



2nd image is the code im using and the output is the 3rd image

Comment: @Chris try my code above..I have used left join...i can't see that in your code.

Comment: yes i added 'left' on the join. still same result. sorry forgot to update the screenshot image

Comment: Ok..@Chris try removing `group_by` clause.

Comment: @Chris i have updated my answer..please update your code and see

Comment: @Chris try adding `group_by` clause..and may i know your table structure?

Comment: this is the experience table

http://pastie.org/10472206

added group_by and the result only displayed 1 data

http://imgur.com/lKEF6BN

Comment: What about `education` table?

Comment: same result. 1 data displayed.. i think ill be using my old code to continue and finish my small system because our deadline is today :( , thank you though

Comment: @Chris please take a look at my answer..i have updated it

Comment: same output. displayed 1 result  :<

Comment: @Chris that can't be..I just tried your code..and it displays me correctly..please copy and paste my code and see.

Comment: how did you display? please comment the code of your view

Comment: I just did a `$q = $this->first->get(14);
  var_dump($q);` it displays me three results..@Chris check my code correctly..It should work...Send me what you have put in your model.

Comment: now its all working fine, just wanna add additional question
is it possible to have 2 foreach statement?

i mean this

foreach($all_data as $results)
{
echo $results['experience sample'];
}

for each($all_data as $results)
{
echo $results['education data'];
}

Comment: @Chris yes you can..But using nested foreach it will cause repeating elements..so rather you can use for loop..Or just tell me what you really need to archive so i can help you.

Comment: ok here's what i really want to achieve

my old controller
http://pastie.org/10472344

my old model
http://pastie.org/10472347

the view
http://pastie.org/10472345

and the output

http://imgur.com/a/vKs6u


i want the to change my MODEL and simplify the code in 1 function.
retrieving all data (5 tables)

Comment: @Chris yes you can archive this in one query..i need other three tables structure.. `projects`,`organization`,`awards`

Comment: awards = http://pastie.org/10472365

organizations = http://pastie.org/10472366

projects = http://pastie.org/10472369

Comment: @Chris i need the `alumni` table too

Comment: @Chris are you there?

Comment: how should i display it?

Answer (score 1):

Hope below mentioned function should return data that you expected.

```
function retrieve_all_data($alumni_id)
{
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('experience ex');
  $this->db->join('education ed','ed.alumni_id=ex.alumni_id');
  $this->db->where('ex.alumni_id',$alumni_id);
  $query=$this->db->get();
  return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: still no data displayed.

Comment: Please make a try catch block to see the error. function retrieve_all_data($alumni_id)
{
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('experience ex');
  $this->db->join('education ed','ed.alumni_id=ex.alumni_id');
  $this->db->where('ex.alumni_id',$alumni_id);
  try{
   $query=$this->db->get();
   return $query->result_array();
  }catch(Exception $e){
 echo $e->getMessage();
 die();
  }
}

Comment: my bad. it retrieved and displayed data. but the problem now is that the data displayed was looped 3times and i dont know why.